# JSON to setAttribute()

Tags: javascript, json

I've almost got the following working, but have run across many confusing approaches. The desire is using the key:value in the attr{} for the setAttribute() method properties, WITHOUT a framework.

Please lend a slim solution:

```
testDiv = document.getElementById("testDiv");


attr = {

    align:"center",
    title:"The Test Div"

};

//Possible converting JSON to String, the use in setAttribute?

for(var x in attr) alert(x + " , " + attr[ x ] );

testDiv.setAttribute( x ,  attr[ x ]);
```

Comment: What's the problem? `for (var x in attr) testDiv.setAttribute(x, attr[x]);` should work fine. Of course there are issues with `setAttribute` itself in IE for non-string attributes; you might want to consider using properties instead. That's still only `for (var x in attr) testDiv[x]= attr[x];` though.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to accomplish? If you simply wish to map attributes to HTML nodes, then your method works fine. Note however that you'll require braces around the block in your for loop or else it will not execute the second statement in the loop. Use: `for (var x in attr) { alert(x + " , " + attr[x]); testDiv.setAttribute(x, attr[x]); }`.

Comment: Found the IE workaround for style:
http://www.peterbe.com/plog/setAttribute-style-IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have JSON there, you have an object literal. Anyway, if I understand you correctly you want to set all of the specified attributes for one particular element? A loop in a function should do it easily enough if you want something re-usable:

```
function setMultipleAttributes(el, attributes) {
   for (var attr in attributes)
     el.setAttribute(attr, attributes[attr]);
}

var testDiv = document.getElementById("testDiv");

setMultipleAttributes(testDiv, { align : "center", title : "The Test Div" });
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the solutions, and jargon clarifications.

Comment: Should I be aware of any IE quirks before attempt extending Element.prototype, with the setMultipleAttributes() method, and should any extensions to the DOM include a custom DTD?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with “JSON” (actually just a JavaScript object literal) or setting attributes. It's this:

```
for(var x in attr) alert(x + " , " + attr[ x ] );

testDiv.setAttribute( x ,  attr[ x ]);
```

Since you do not use braces with the `for` loop, only the statement immediately following it is executed. If I add braces, the above code looks like this:

```
for(var x in attr){
    alert(x + " , " + attr[x] );
}
testDiv.setAttribute( x ,  attr[x]);
```

`setAttribute` isn’t called in the loop — it’s just called once at the end. Instead, you probably want…

```
for(var x in attr){
    alert(x + " , " + attr[x] );
    testDiv.setAttribute( x ,  attr[x]);
}
```